# jQuery Ajax always returns 'object'

Tags: ajax, jquery, validation, prototypejs

I have some code that validates a form using Prototype but I want to add a jQuery ajax function to check if the username already exists in the database. However, the value being returned by jQuery is always an object and not the boolean of whether the username exists or not. Here is my code so far:

validation.js

```
//Using Prototype
Validation.addAllThese([

    ['validate-username', 'Username already exists. Please choose another one.', 
      function (v) {     //v is the value of the username field in the form.

        //Using jQuery
        var match = jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/php/ajax/check_username_exists.php",
                        data: {username: v},
                        async: false
                    });
        return (match.responseText == v);

]);
```

check_username_exists.php

```
<?php
include '../library.php';
include '../config.php';

//Echo string username if matches
echo select_row("USERNAME", "members", "USERNAME='".$_GET['username']."'");
?>
```

I have checked other threads on StackOverflow including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768991/return-value-of-jquery-ajax-call) but none seem to fix the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, jQuery.ajax returns a jqXHR object. That's what it is supposed to do.

Comment: So how do I return the value of data in the validation function?

Comment: @Daniel you can't return from an ajax callback.  Any work that relies on the result of the ajax call must be done in the callback

Comment: There is no "done" option, use "success" instead.

Comment: Can you show us your server side code. I think maybe you are getting JSON data from server.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Yes, I added the code from the PHP script.

Comment: @Daniel Have you logged the `data` on the console? Try: `console.log(data)` or `alert(data);` in your javascript code and tell us the result. Besides what kind of data returns form `select_row` function in your php code ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, Here is the solution code:

```
var match = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/php/ajax/check_username_exists.php",
    data: {username: v},
    async: false
});
return (match.responseText != v);
```

Return was supposed to be **false** when invalidated. So I had it returned **true** if the username existed which was supposed to be **false**. A simple change from `==` to `!=` fixed the problem.